# How to interpret statements such as "There is weak evidence for..."

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

When I read a Cochrane study or something from NCBI that says there is weak evidence for X, does it follow there is also weak evidence for NOT X?

Does this follow for review statistics where a number of studies are used?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I'd interpret it as roughly "We have suggestive but inconclusive evidence for X. All else being equal, we think it's more likely than Not-X".

I'll note that this confusion around communication of weak results seems to be less of an issue when the analysis is done in a Bayesian framework. The prior is defined and so there's less need to argue over what the default belief should be when the data does not point strongly in one direction.

Comment: Should the article provide some sort of metric? Is it a poor analysis if there is not one? I understand the prior reference. But in review data I am not sure there is a prior. Am I asking a poor question here and in the main question?

Comment: @psitee Well, the statement should definitely be backed up by the statistical analysis. You'll have to look into the details of the model and the results to see this.

Comment: @psitee Also, the "We have weak evidence for X" formulation is most commonly used when the analysis returns p-values that are in the 0.05 to 0.15 range. Sometimes they call the results 'marginally significant' if the p-value is between 0.05 and 0.10

Comment: I found this also: <https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270585/is-there-hypothesis-testing-to-describe-weak-no-correlation?rq=1>

Comment: OK - a number of thoughts and articles to review. thanks. So back to the tank :)